# Access item inside div through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div which contain other tags inside it

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>item</td>
                      <td>item</td>
                      <td>2</td>
                   </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>item</td>
                      <td>item</td>
                      <td>5</td>
                   </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I access `<td>` of this mainDiv through javascript. I want to change innerHTML of these `<td>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var allDivTd = document.getElementById("mainDiv").getElementsByTagName("TD");

for(var i = 0; i < allDivTd.length; i++){
    var td = allDivTd[i];
    td.innerHTML = // do something w/ inner html
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery: `$('div#mainDiv td')` will return a set with all `<td>`s in it.

You can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to modify the content of them. See http://jsfiddle.net/StuperUser/vD3Tk/ for an example.

Use jQuery if you're doing a lot of JS and have a lot of DOM manipulation to do. It has powerful and terse selector syntax from CSS, a lot of extension methods for DOM manipulation and cross browser compatibility. However, if you're only doing a small amount of JS, then don't feel it's necessary.

Comment: Edit your answer - you need a few quotes :)

Comment: It's good to refer to jquery for these kinds of situation. However, I would have +1'ed you if you give him the reasons to use jquery.

Comment: Or in Prototype.js $$('div#mainDiv td')

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed, Brian's answer is accurate for the OP, since if he's only manipulating the table, using the jQuery library may be overkill. If he's doing a lot of JS then I've included some of the best reasons for using jQuery.

Comment: @StuperUser should be echoed a thousand times from the highest mountain. jQuery is not a substitute for JavaScript. It is a high demand framework that simplifies difficult tasks and chaining in JavaScript, and is not applicable to all scenarios. I find there are far too many folks out there that "know" jQuery and don't know JavaScript - a scenario I'd have thought to be impossible just a few years ago.

Comment: @StuperUser: Good, since you have included the reasons to use jquery, it's high time I give you a +1!. And I agree with Brian, jQuery cannot be a substitute for javascript, it is a library which simplifies things. That's why I requested you to include those reasons :-) .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to get all the `tr` tags, and then iterate over them for accessing the individual `td`s:

```
trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var tds = trs[i].childNodes;
        for (var J = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
            var td = tds.childNodes[j];
            // process td
        }
    }
}
```

Although , as you can see, this doesn't look to nice and is quite verbose. It's easier to use a Javascript framework such as jQuery, mootools, dojo... for these kinds of tasks. They support CSS selectors (e.g. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) that let you traverse the DOM using CSS selectors, which are similar to XPath-style expressions and much more powerful than manual dom traversal with the few functions that Javascript originally provides for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var children = document.getElementById('mainDiv').getElementsByTagName('td');
```